# How can I destroy session in Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I try this but not working. When I click on forward button of browser after logout button, browser redirect me again on welcome page, without login details.

```
public ActionResult studentlogout()
{

    Session.Clear();

    Session.Abandon();

    Session.RemoveAll();

    Session["student"] = null;

    return RedirectToAction("studentlogin");

}
```

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Working on MVC 5

Comment: Aside: there's no need to add "please help" and "thanks in advance" and other filler material in your questions, especially in the title, where succinctness is especially expected. Since some people say "please help" when they mean to beg and/or ask someone to write code for them, it is especially worth avoiding.

Comment: What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Authentication usually has nothing to do with Session state.